# How to avoid Pylance's "reportUnnecessaryIsinstance"?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I'm not quite sure what the purpose of reporting unnecessary isinstance is and I tend to regularly get warnings about it in my setters when I do something like:

```py
@foo.setter
def foo(self, val: int):
    if not isinstance(val, int):
        raise ValueError()
```

So here Pylance gives me the warning that *"an int is always an instance of int"* which certainly makes sense, but I want to ensure what has been supplied was actually an int and terminate the code with error if it isn't.

Other ways of typing to avoid this particular warning I've been thinking of:

```py
@foo.setter
def foo(self, val):    
    if not isinstance(val, int):
        raise ValueError()
```

In this case I of course get a warning that `the type of val is unknown` instead. Finally, there's this option which clears all warnings but I'm not certain that using `Any` in this way is sensible:

```py
@foo.setter
def foo(self, val: Any):
    if not isinstance(val, int):
        raise ValueError()
```

Which of these is more correct syntactically and semantically? Or maybe I should just disable this warning in the settings?

Comment: Well, do you want the code to do the type checking, or do you want a static code checker to read the annotations and do it? What *problem are you trying to solve* by using Pylance in the first place?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, in this particular case I want my code to do the necessary type checking but I also don't want to see warnings if there's a way to avoid having them.

Comment: Not a Pylance user, so I could be all wrong here, but I would guess the purpose of the reportUnnecessaryIsinstance feature is because the use of isinstance violates the Liskov substitution principle (LSP), one of the SOLID principles of object-oriented programming. The SOLID principles are designed to create code that is easier to maintain. If your code is not object-oriented, I would expect (though I'm far from an expert) that the enforcement of the LSP is not relevant.